# Solr 9 Windows: how to index directory with spaces in name

Tags: java, windows, indexing, solr, lucene

I'm using post.jar (on Windows 10) to index directories. I cannot figure out the syntax to use for directories with spaces in their names. Here is an example (using single quotes):

```
X:\yada\solr-9.0.0> java -jar -Dc=cd1 -Dauto -Drecursive=5 .\post.jar 'P:\projects\blah\spaces in this dir name\*'
```

I've tried escaping the spaces, putting the path inside double and single quotes, backticks.

Comment: In general, at the OS level, enclosing in double quotes will make it produce a single argument. Do you get any errors?

Comment: No errors. Just the output '0 files indexed.'

Answer (score 1):

For a directory that has spaces in the name and is not a shortcut, I found that it worked if I left off the `\*` at the end of the directory to be indexed:

```
X:\yada\solr-9.0.0> java -jar -Dc=cd1 -Dauto -Drecursive=5 .\post.jar 'P:\projects\blah\spaces in this dir name'
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Mark. It turns out the directory was a shortcut. Testing with other shortcuts to non_space_directories confirmed.